# How can I get an article's URL in a Joomla content plugin?

Tags: url, plugins, joomla, joomla1.5

I am trying to write a plugin that needs articles' URL and I can't get it in content plugin. I am getting some with JURI::current() but it doesn't work in frontpage and other sections and categories?

How can I get an article's URL in a Joomla content plugin just to use it between Title and Content itself in Joomla 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

With a classical PHP call? I've never write a Joomla plugin...

```
$myUrl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```